# How to redirect traffic from .svc.cluster.local to .svc.k8s.my-domain.com in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, dns, yaml, coredns, yugabytedb

My cluster has its own domain name `k8s.my-domain.com`.

Originally when I deploy Dgraph, I met issue that their pods cannot talk to each other by `dgraph-service.dgraph-namespace.svc.cluster.local`.

If they talk to each other by

- `dgraph-service.dgraph-namespace`
- `dgraph-service.dgraph-namespace.svc.k8s.my-domain.com`

it will work.

I fixed by removing `.svc.cluster.local` part from Dgraph yaml and created the pull request at https://github.com/dgraph-io/dgraph/pull/7976.

Today, when I deploy Yugabyte, I met the same issue again. I created a ticket at https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-operator/issues/38 and hopefully Yugabyte team can fix it.

However, I am not sure if this approach is good now. I hope I can do something on my side.

Is there a way to redirect from `.svc.cluster.local` to `.svc.k8s.my-domain.com`?
Maybe in CoreDNS so that I don't need to change original Dgraph or Yugabyte YAML file? Thanks!

---

**UPDATE 1:**

Based on @CodeWizard suggestion, and because I got a warning from my IDE:

[image]

So I tried both versions:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: k8s.my-domain.com
```

and

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: external-service
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: cluster.local
```

After applying this yaml file.

However, I still got same error deploying Yugabyte to my cluster.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ExternalName` in your service.

```
kind: "Service"
apiVersion: "v1"
metadata:
  name: "external-mysql-service"
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: example.domain.name
selector: {} # The selector field to leave blank.
```

#### Using an External Domain Name

- Using external domain names makes it easier to manage an external service because you do not have to worry about the external service’s IP addresses changing.
- You can use an ExternalName service to direct traffic to an external service.
- Using an external domain name service tells the system that the DNS name in the `externalName` field (example.domain.name in the previous example) is the location of the resource that backs the service.
- When a DNS request is made against the Kubernetes DNS server, it returns the `externalName` in a CNAME record telling the client to look up the returned name to get the IP address.

Comment: Hi @CodeWizard I am not sure I understand correctly. I am actually having issue deploying for example, Yugabyte, to my cluster when my cluster has a domain name. If my cluster do not have domain name, there won't be issue deploying Yugabyte. Yugabyte its own services try to talk to each other by `yugabyte-service.yugabyte-namespace.svc.cluster.local` which failed because my cluster has domain name `k8s.my-domain.com`. If they talk to each other by `yugabyte-service.yugabyte-namespace` or `yugabyte-service.yugabyte-namespace.svc.k8s.my-domain.com`, it will work.